# a method returning double adding to string and printing to 2 decimal places

Tags: java, methods, return, decimal, tostring

I am trying to print a double returned from a method to 2 decimal places but I am having trouble as the method is called in the return of a string method.

I have tried using printf but I get an error. I am assuming this is because there is not only numbers.

heres the code.

```
public double monthlyPay()
{
    return annualSalary / 12;
}

public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + " Monthly Pay = " + monthlyPay();
}

public void print()
{
    System.out.println(toString());
}
```

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Take a lock at the class java.text.NumberFormat

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to cut `monthlyPay()` to 2 decimal places you can go with:

```
double monthPay =  (double)Math.round(monthlyPay() * 100d) / 100d

return super.toString() + " Monthly Pay = " + monthPay);
```

Alternatively you can use a method like this to format your string:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public static String formatNumber(int decimals, double number) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(decimals + 2);
    sb.append("#.");
    for(int i = 0; i < decimals; i++) {
        sb.append("0");
    }
    return new DecimalFormat(sb.toString()).format(number);
}
```

It surely does output zeros aswell. Upon calling it with these parameters for example:

```
 String x =  formatNumber(3,5.1000);
```

your output will be `x = "5,100"`

Comment: You can't invoke `toString()` on a primitive, they're not objects

Comment: thanks but i still not getting it to 2 decimal places it rounds it up to 1.1 when i want it 1.10

Comment: i found this 

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(df.format(decimalNumber)); but it wants me to make a class for it to work is there any other way?

Comment: You can try to df.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthPay)); but im not sure if it otuputs zeros and cannot test right away.